# How to change values in an area of an array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,1,3],[6,7,1]])

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 1, 3],
       [6, 7, 1]])
```

I need to transform every 1 to a 23 but only on a subset of the array. 
I want to start at the index 1:1 and stop at 2:2

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 23, 3],
       [6, 7, 23]])
```

Comment: What's the code for your search function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>>A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,1,3],[6,7,1]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 1, 3],
       [6, 7, 1]])

>>>b = A[1:,1:]==1
>>>A[1:,1:][b]=23
>>>A
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4, 23,  3],
       [ 6,  7, 23]])
```